# type arabic font in html text fields

Tags: html, fonts, arabic

my requirement is to have an application which takes Arabic data as input in an html text field. i tried a few fonts but they don't let me type Arabic in html text field.any pointers

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Conv_ScheherazadeRegOT';
    src: url('fonts/ScheherazadeRegOT.eot');
    src: local('â˜º'), url('fonts/ScheherazadeRegOT.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/ScheherazadeRegOT.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/ScheherazadeRegOT.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}



input
    {
        font-family:'Conv_ScheherazadeRegOT',Sans-Serif;        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp) list of web-safe fonts and feel free to choose whichever of them supports arabic. Note that a custom font (search @font-face) is not a bad idea since many platforms and browsers often use fallback fonts instead of the ones specified in a webpage. You can see some free-for-commercial-use fonts [here](http://www.fontspace.com/).

Answer (score 0):

And make sure that you set up meta charset with UTF8!

Answer (score 0):

The suitable generic fonts like "Arial","Times New Roman".. before that you should check the page encoding (eg. utf-8).. and set the non-unicodes option at your OS to support arabic.

Comment: i can copy paste and arabic text into the text field and it works fine, but how to type it in arabic? or is there an option like that at all ?

Comment: yes sure.. make sure that your PC support Arabic lang. from the control panel->regional Settings (if you are using windows).

Comment: if so..   switch to Arabic language using(right **ALT+Shift**)

Comment: What happened when you pressed your keyboard keys? what kinds of characters were appeared?

Comment: thanks alt shift works fine, but will the @font-face css tags not work for Arabic typing, without using windows language features..?