# how can i switch between Arabic and English language in html webpage textfield

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

how can i enable Arabic typing in an html website using java-script, i have a application where the user can switch languages between English and Arabic and type them in a text field. I tried font-faces but it did not work.

Comment: HTML and CSS do not deal with input methods. Whatever methods the user can deploy in general when using a web page can be used; you cannot disable or enable such things in HTML and CSS. You can create input widgets with JavaScript, but that would be a different question.

Comment: Isn't this basically the same question as the one you asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672505/type-arabic-font-in-html-text-fields#comment27509729_18672628)? It sounds like you're trying to switch the users' keyboard input method to Arabic from the website.

Comment: yes i am trying to switch the users input language from English to Arabic with font-faces, am i going in the right way or will it ever work. with java script and html ..?

Comment: The font in which things are displayed has nothing to do with which input language the user's computer is currently using. There seem to be Javascript libraries that help; see, for instance, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008390/arabic-text-box).

Comment: Thanks MR Lister this served my purpose .. http://ankitpokhrel.com.np/unicode-js/